# Use adb before screen unlock

Tags: adb

I'm kinda in an argument here and I want a definite answer

On any device I've used, adb can't be used before I unlock my screen. I'm being told it can, you just can't access storage

So can adb be used before screen unlock, or is it OEM dependent?

Comment: I have used adb on both Nexus 6 and OnePlus 6 with screen lock on and screen off. Are you sure this is not about granting authorisation to the RSA fingerprint dialog? Because that requires unlocking the screen. Which device is it?

Comment: @Firelord I've tested with Moto g6, g7, and Alcatel tetra, and Samsung Galaxy j3 Luna pro. I know once I've unlocked once after attach to the PC and activate adb, it'll continue working. Just if the screen is locked on plugging it in (eg just booted) it won't work (I think)

Comment: It works here in OnePlus 6 even when encrypted, restarted, and the decryption password not entered. Probably OEM dependent, but let's wait for others to chime in.

Comment: @Firelord ok. Seems to be mostly flagship models that can use adb on a locked screen so far

Comment: On my Sony XA2 (Android 9 with FBE), adb also works directly after reboot (before SIM card and device unlock). Of course before I enter the device unlock PIN the files (e.g. on /storage/emulated/0) are still FBE encrypted.